Encountered, Previously working, Application.Keys registration problem
My operating system is 64 bit Windows 10.
I use 32 bit Office 19 Professional, Upgraded from 32 bit Office 16 Professional. The following worked in Excel under Office 16 and, after upgrading, Office 19. Although I attempted to change to Office 64 bit during the upgrade, the 32 bit version was installed.
On opening my Excel application, I set several shortcut keys as "^+{?}",Procedure where ? = an alpha key. I wrote a VBA code that read the 'key' and 'procedure' from a range I created on an worksheet. I use this same methodology in three different excel applications and have been doing so for the last three plus years without any problems.
All Three (3) excel applications use the same key settings however, while procedure names are the same in two (2) applications, the third (3rd) use different procedure names that direct to the same function as used in all three (3) applications.
I use a boolean parameter for the same VBA function to reset all keys on closing of an application.
Since 11 May 2024 the methodology still work on two (2) of the applications but keys do not register on opening of the Third (3rd) application, immaterial if I register keys using the function or attempting to register keys individually and with direct provided parameters.
I checked the VBA references and all selections are correct as initially selected.
However, on the control panel application, I noticed that office did updates to all office applications on 10 May 2024.
In anticipation of a response, I will address the 'procedure' names in the third application as possibly the problem because I used 'keyA', 'keyK', etc. as procedure names.

Found the problem.
Seems Excel now does not like any reference to 'key' in the procedure of the Application.OnKey (String, Procedure) method. After I changed the procedure name, removing 'key' from the procedure, is the application back to normal.
